How to plasterboard across exposed damp proof course?
I have an integrated garage with my house that was built after the house. As such one of the walls of the garage is formerly the outside wall of the house and has a damp proof course layer a little bit off the floor. I want to put plasterboard up in the garage to make it cleaner/more usable as a workshop.
What approach should be taken when doing this? Is there any special considerations that need to be made in order to avoid any issues with bridging the DPC?
Below is an image of the bottom of the wall I want to plasterboard. The original DPC is between the bricks and the breeze blocks. The garage floor is concrete and you can see another blue DPC that was laid for this. The exposed bricks are below any DPC.

